# How to start a song with a button and stop the song with same button if song is still playing

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Python 3.7.3 and Raspberry Pi 4 console app and 1 momentary button

My current python script will launch and wait for the press of the button to start playing the hard-coded song.

What I need is for my python script to start playing a hard-coded song on button press and also be able to stop that song with the press of the same button again.  Or, at the bare minimum use a second button to "reset" the song and put system back to waiting for first button press to start song.

I am using gpiozero Buttons and the when_pressed event to call a function to play the song.

Any ideas?

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

alarm = AudioSegment.from_file("alarm.mp3")
alarmState = False

buttonReset = Button(20)
buttonAlarm = Button(21)

def alarmOn():
    global alarmState
    alarmState = True
    print("Play: " + str(alarmState))
    
    while alarmState:
        play(alarm)

def alarmReset():
    global alarmState
    print("Alarm Reset: " + str(alarmState))
    
    alarmState = False
    
try:
    print("Program Start: " + str(alarmState))
    
    buttonAlarm.when_pressed = alarmOn
    
    buttonReset.when_pressed = alarmReset
    
    pause()
finally:
    pass
```

Comment: Please, provide us with code examples

Comment: Your code keeps inside the `while alarmstate` check this answer https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/80414/gpio-wait-for-edge-and-signal-signal

Comment: That code uses rpi.gpio and in many threads people mention to not use that module.  They say it can be outdated and prone to board isolation for updating hardware.  Everyone says to use the gpizero module instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding a solution by changing to a different player that includes a "stop" feature.  See code below.

```py
from omxplayer.player import OMXPlayer
from time import sleep
from signal import pause
from gpiozero import Button

alarmState = False
player = None

def playerExit(exit_code):
    global alarmState
    
    alarmState = False

def alarmOn():
    global alarmState
    global player
    
    alarmState = True
    player = OMXPlayer(alarmFile)
    player.set_volume(1)
    player.exitEvent += lambda _, exit_code: playerExit(exit_code)

def alarmReset():
    global alarmState
    global player

    if player != None:
        if alarmState:
            player.stop()

try:
    alarmFile = "alarm-long.mp3"

    buttonReset = Button(20)
    buttonAlarm = Button(21)
    
    buttonAlarm.when_pressed = alarmOn
    buttonReset.when_pressed = alarmReset
    
    pause()
finally:
    pass
```